# Losing ZF2 Session after Paypal redirection

Tags: php, paypal, zend-framework2

I have a serious problem with managing session in zf2 and PayPal payment. Once I get in the page of the payment, I lose the zf2 session.
How to solve it?

```
$mySession = new Container('mySession');
$mySession->login = "name";
$mySession->droit=  "admin";
```

Thanks.

**Update :**
the redirect page :

```
<?php
  session_start();
 extract($_GET);
if($action == "paypal")
  header("Location: ./paymentgetway.php?action=$action&invoiceId=$invoiceId&L_NAME0=$L_NAME0&L_AMT0=$L_AMT0&L_DESC0=$L_DESC0&L_QTY0=$L_QTY0");
?>
```

the payment page :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once ("payment/paypal/paypalfunctions.php");
    extract($_GET);
    extract($_SESSION);
    switch ($action) {
        case "paypal":
            if (isset($L_NAME0) && isset($L_AMT0) && isset($L_DESC0) && isset($L_QTY0)) {
                include("payment/paypal/expresscheckout.php");
            } else {
                header("Location:index.php");
            }
            break;
        case "paymentcanceled":
            $file = "payment/paypal/paymentcanceled.php";
            break;
        case "paymentcompleted":
            if ($paymentapi == "paypal") {
                include("payment/saveTransactionDetails.php");
            }
            $file = "payment/paypal/paymentcompleted.php";
            break;
        case "paymentpending":
            $file = "payment/paypal/paymentpending.php";
            break;
        case "apierror":
            $file = "payment/paypal/apierror.php";
            break;
        default:
            header("Location: index.php");
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">      
        <body>  
            <div class="corps">
                <?php include($file); ?>   
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you. How are you checking the session on the payment page? Can you verify whether or not the sessions are being created?

Comment: Are you saving your sessions? I believe to make `Containers` persist you need to save them. This could be memcached, redis, db... The docs are pretty poor but [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.config.html) is a good starting point.

Comment: @Svengali : nop , i don't use any tool to save the zf2 session cause i don't need that they persist.i work with it around the application.the problem is that once i get the page of the paypal payment , the zf2 session breaks.

Comment: @TimFountain i guess that the problem is that i'm obligated to use both session php in the payment page and zf2 session for the appl.

Comment: You don't need to manually 'save' the session, this happens automatically, as it does in PHP. @user3911183 the ZF2 session class is just a wrapper around the native PHP session functionality, using both shouldn't be an issue. But we would still need to see your payment page session code in order to suggest what the issue might be.

Comment: ok , i have many pages , first one for redirection and the second one is for the calling and require payment paypal api.which one will be useful ?

Comment: Neither your redirect or payment page seem to be using the data your put in the session as far as I can see. Can you clarify exactly what it is that isn't working?

Comment: ok , after doing many test , i recognise that the problem comes from session_start() in the script , when i use session_start() the SessionManager in the ZF2 application log off.

Comment: But what makes you think that the ZF2 application 'logs off'? At what point are you trying to access session data that is no longer there?

Comment: once i go to the ZF2 application , i refresh or i go to an action , it send me to the login page.

Comment: Are you using any custom session configuration? E.g. storing sessions in the database, or in memcache.

Comment: no , i'm using the native session container of zf2.nothing the custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to use the modul realised for zf2 which is speckPaypal , here is the tuto i followed to make it work :

http://phpcantho24h.blogspot.com/2014/04/paypal-express-checkout-creating-simple.html

Hope it helps.